# Is it possible to convert the singular matrix into invertible matrix by setting some columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose square matrix $A$ whose size are $n$ x $n$  having a determinant equals to $0$. Is it possible to convert it into invertible matrix by setting maximum three columns into any specific values?

If so, What supposed to be the value of those columns ?

Comment: Basic example - the matrix where every element is zero. You will need to think about the rank of the matrix.

Comment: @Prometheus you mean regardless the rank of the matrix ?

Comment: @MarkBennet The matrix $A$ is different than zero.

Comment: If different from zero - make one entry non-zero. As I indicated the concept you need is rank (or nullity).

Comment: @F Two examples of matrices with $\operatorname{rank}(A) < n-3$:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right),\\
\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\ 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\ 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\ 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\ 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 \end{array}\right)
$$
For both of these, it is impossible to make the matrix invertible by changing three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, then no. Imagine following matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
Then you cant convert into invertible matrix by setting maximum three columns. If rank(A)=n-3, then maybe.

Comment: You mean to have invertible matrix, the rank(A) must be at least $n-3$ ? by the way, my matrix $A$ is different than 0

Comment: For invertible matrix must be rank(A)=n. For your problem rank(A)=n-3 (for setting maximum three columns).

Comment: You mean for the case where $A = 0$, in that case the $rank(A) = n-3$.

Comment: If A=0, then rank(A)=0 and n=4, so it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In general, as previously described, the main concept is rank, which is the dimension of the space spanned by A's columns.
If $rank(A) >n-3$ then it has at most three columns linearly dependent on the rest, if we replace them with independent one, we get an invertible matrix(because all whose columns are linearly independent).
else, it cannot be done, as we have four or more such columns that can not all be replaced.